# How to Assign TextBoxes Multiple Values from ScriptNotify

Tags: c#, javascript, html, windows-phone-8

I have a Javascript function and I am calling that function via InvokeScript using C#. The function gathers multiple values, and currently I am returning them in a single string. I'd like to be able to separate the values that the function returns and assign each one to a particular TextBox in C# instead of all to a single TextBox. I need the values to be separated and shown in different places in my View. How might I do this? Currently I have the following setup.

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
private string MainUri = "/Html/index.html";

private void Browser_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //tell the browser the URL to navigate to
        Browser.Navigate(new Uri(MainUri, UriKind.Relative));
    }

private void Browser_ScriptNotify(object sender, NotifyEventArgs e)
    {
        TestResultTextBlock.Text = e.Value.ToString(); //contains all values from the JavaScript function, needs to be separated somehow
    }

private void RunTestButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        object result1 = Browser.InvokeScript("getStatistics");
    }
```

index.html

```
function getStatistics()
    {
        var timing = window.performance.timing;

        window.external.notify(
              "Statistics:" +
            "\ndns: " + (timing.domainLookupEnd - timing.domainLookupStart).toString() +
            "\nconnect: " + (timing.connectEnd - timing.connectStart).toString()
            );
    }
```

Right now I have no choice but to start a new line for each of the values I need to collect. Is there way to separate these so that separate TextBoxes can get their appropriate values?

Comment: Why not return a stringified Json object and deserialize it in c#?

Comment: Good point. From my early research it seemed that JSON was for datatypes that were not strings. I created two separate functions, but this probably wasn't the best fix, although it worked for my needs.

Comment: It's just a serialization format. You could use a character delimiter and grab pieces of the string, or XML as well.